# Unable to publish a SharePoint 2010 workflow from SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am working on a client requirement where I have to create `List Workflows` for `O365 - SharePoint Online` websites.

When I try publishing the workflow, I get an error which says - `unexpected error while publishing workflow`.

The workflow actually does not have any errors which may forbid it from being published but still I am getting this error. I have researched a lot on this but have not managed to get any fix for this.

The following is the workflow:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: can you attach any screenshot of error or screenshot of workflow actions? that might be helpful for us to answer your question.

Comment: Error window shows that there are errors while compiling the workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue published via Office 365 Admin Center->Health->Service Health->Advisories->SharePoint Online:

"SP175429- Unable to edit existing workflows or create new workflows"

That users are unable to edit workflows or create new workflows in SharePoint 2010 using Designer and other protocols.

[image]

You can check the status about this issue via service health.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the complexity of the workflow. [Here](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-To-Identify-Complexity-of-SharePoint-2013-or-2010-Workflow-to-fix-errors-while-compilation) is a link where you can find the Powershell script to check it. If the complexity is more than 7000(default threshold for SharePoint online), you may need to split the workflow.

Comment: The workflow only has a single line of action. I am only updating a list item using the workflow even then I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you're sure that the workflow has no errors, you may try out these two checks -

- Make sure that you have sufficient space in C drive of the server/machine where you're publishing this workflow
- Ensure that all the workflow related features are enabled in both the site collection level as well as site level.

Let me know if error still persists